# How to use libnetfilter_conntrack on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: netfilter, ubuntu-18.04

I'm playing to capture the packet by libnetfilter_conntrack

The following code has worked so far on Ubuntu except Ubuntu 18.04.

There's no output despite browsing or accessing ssh.

Do you know why???

```
static int cb(enum nf_conntrack_msg_type eMsgType,
                struct nf_conntrack *psConntrack,
                void *pvData)
{
    char buf[1024] = {0,};

    nfct_snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), psConntrack, eMsgType, NFCT_O_DEFAULT, NFCT_OF_TIME);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return NFCT_CB_STOP;
}
int main()
{
    struct nfct_handle *pSNfctHandle;

    pSNfctHandle = nfct_open(CONNTRACK, NFCT_ALL_CT_GROUPS);
    nfct_callback_register(pSNfctHandle, NFCT_T_ALL, cb, NULL);

    nfct_catch(pSNfctHandle);
    nfct_close(pSNfctHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

I tested after adding nf_conntrack, nf_conntrack_ipv4, nf_conntrack_netlink kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue on 18.04. So far the only known solution is the command "ufw enable" but it's pretty high-level. Would be nice to know any more atomic operations to re-enable netfilter functionality on Ubuntu 18.x. Suggestions are more then welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**ufw enable** is too powerful stuff :)

Instead of the command:

> ufw enable

Add the following firewall rules:

```
/sbin/iptables -t filter -I OUTPUT  1 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
/sbin/ip6tables -t filter -I OUTPUT  1 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

If necessary, you can also use the INPUT and FORWARD chains